# Unable to change the background color of my bottom navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a clone of the google homepage as one of my first html/css projects. This is the first time I've ever coded and I'm having trouble with setting the background colour for one of the navigation bars at the bottom of the screen. I was able to set the background colour of the upper navigation bar (the one with the country name on it) but when I try to set the background colour for the lower navigation bar (the one with the Advertising and Business links) it doesn't show and the bar remains white.

This is my html code for the lower navigation bars

```
<footer class="bottom_nav">
    <div class="country_nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Canada</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom_nav_l">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#advertising">Advertising</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="#howsearchworks">How Search Works</a></li>
        <ul>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_nav_r">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

This is my CSS

```
.country_nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.country_nav li {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.bottom_nav_l li {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 14px; 
}

.bottom_nav_r li {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.bottom_nav_l li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
}

.bottom_nav_r li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
}

.bottom_nav_l li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom_nav_r li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom_nav_l {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.bottom_nav_r {
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.bottom_nav {
    padding-top: 170px;
}
```

And this is what the page looks like for reference. I want the lowest bar to be grey as well.
[google homepage clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrAC5.png)

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `ul` `li`. You can wrap your `bottom link` in to div and use `display: flex` and `justfify-content:space-between` to have space between your link.

Also i have modified the `a` links to match exactly as google footer by adding padding and `text-decoration:none`

Exact copy of google footer in demo.

> Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kx291hqm/

Run snippet below.

```css
.country_nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 27px;
}


.bottom_nav_l li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom_nav_r li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
}

.bottom_nav_l li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom_nav_r li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom_nav_r {
    padding-right: 27px;
}

.bottom_nav {
    padding-top: 170px;
}

.bottom_link {
      display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
        line-height: 40px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
   color: #5f6368;
   padding-left: 27px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="bottom_nav">
  <div class="country_nav">
    Canada
  </div>
  <div class="bottom_link">
    <div class="bottom_nav_l">
      <a href="#advertising">Advertising</a>
      <a href="#business">Business</a>
      <a href="#howsearchworks">How Search Works</a>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_nav_r">
      <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
      <a href="#terms">Terms</a>
      <a href="#privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: It would be still better to make it a list so that screen reader can quick jump to it and navigate through it and announce it properly. You can change the display of your list to flex but it's better to leave it a list tag. Otherwise you have to get into aria roles, which is for a list not all that too complex tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding following css:

```
.bottom_nav{
background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .country_nav {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
            border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
            padding-top: -1px;
            padding-bottom: 1px;
            padding-left: 25px;
        }

        .country_nav li {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            margin-left: -10px;
        }

        section{
            background-color: #ebebeb;
        }

        .bottom_nav_l li {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;

        }

        .bottom_nav_r li {
            float: right;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .bottom_nav_l li a {
            display: block;
            margin-left: -10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .bottom_nav_r li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
        }

        .bottom_nav_l li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .bottom_nav_r li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .bottom_nav_l {
            padding-left: 15px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        .bottom_nav_r {
            padding-right: 15px;
            background-color: #d7d7d7;
        }

        .bottom_nav {
            padding-top: 0px;
            position: relative;
            top: 460px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<footer class="bottom_nav">
    <div class="country_nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Canada</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section>
        <div class="bottom_nav_l">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#advertising">Advertising</a></li>
                <li><a href="#business">Business</a></li>
                <li><a href="#howsearchworks">How Search Works</a></li>
                <ul>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom_nav_r">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```